# Trouble running our Vaadin application with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, vaadin, vaadin-flow

We recently switched to Gradle. Our stack is Vaadin 23, embedded Jetty, and Guice. When we run our main method through IntelliJ, everything works as expected. However, we want to run it from Gradle, which we set up. It works perfect on macOS and Ubuntu, but not on Windows.

Here is our Gradle task (simplified):

```kotlin
create<JavaExec>("startWebapp") {
    dependsOn("vaadinPrepareFrontend")

    group = "mycompany"
    classpath = sourceSets.named("main").get().runtimeClasspath
    mainClass.set("com.mycompany.portal.Portal")
    workingDir = project.projectDir
}
```

We get the following exception on startup:

```
12:34:56.837 [main] [1] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5c18556c{PORTAL,/,[file:///C:/Users/oliver/IdeaProjects/mycompany/webapp/build/resources/main/webapp/],UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application Lookup instance is not found in VaadinContext. The instance is suppoed to be created by a ServletContainerInitializer. Issues known to cause this problem are:
- A Spring Boot application deployed as a war-file but the main application class does not extend SpringBootServletInitializer
- An embedded server that is not set up to execute ServletContainerInitializers
- Unit tests which do not properly set up the context for the test

    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:54)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:48)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createPropertyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:82)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer$StubServletConfig.createDeploymentConfiguration(ServletDeployer.java:185)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.lambda$getServletConfigurations$0(ServletDeployer.java:280)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.getServletConfigurations(ServletDeployer.java:279)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.contextInitialized(ServletDeployer.java:194)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at com.mycompany.portal.bootstrap.JettyService.start(JettyService.java:60)
    at com.mycompany.portal.Portal.startServer(Portal.java:88)
    at com.mycompany.portal.Portal.main(Portal.java:42)
```

I did some digging. It seems that, when running through Gradle, the `classSet` of `LookupServletContainerInitializer#process` is empty. What I have tried:

- Compared the classpaths when running from IntelliJ to Gradle. They are the same. Only difference is that Gradle creates a temporary JAR with a manifest file, so any non-jar folders, such as `src/main/java` is prefixed with `file://`.
- I think Gradle uses its own classloader, so I manually set the classloader in Jetty.
- I tried to make a minimal, reproducible example, but could not reproduce the issue.
- I tried manually adding the missing classes to `classSet`. The app then starts up, but is unusable. E.g., the app is just plaintext.

Comment: You probably have a similar bug in gradle as pointed out in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77061312/775715